# Using GraphQL in a GitHub Action does not return anything for `requiredApprovingReviewCount`

Tags: github, graphql, jq, github-actions

I am writing a GitHub Action to try and automate our (beta) project board. I need to take into account the number of required reviews before I move the issue or PR into the `Approved` column.

In trying to get the count of required reviews it always returns nothing. I have run this exact query in the [GitHub GraphQL Explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer) and also checked my jq query in this [JQ Play snippet](https://jqplay.org/s/QISpYx7_VBs). These both return the correct value (in my test case this is `1`).

However when moving this to a GitHub Action it returns: `REVIEW_REQUIRED_COUNT=`

My expected output is: `REVIEW_REQUIRED_COUNT= 1`

I have also tried to play around with the GITHUB_TOKEN permissions, as I think this could be the error but to no avail, I have hit a brick wall - please can someone help?

```
---

name: MY ACTION

"on":
  pull_request:
    branches: [develop, master]

env:
  PR_URL: ${{ github.event.pull_request.html_url }}
  GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.MY_GITHUB_TOKEN }}

jobs:
    my-job:
      name: My Job 
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      permissions: read-all
      steps:
        - name: Get req review count
          id: review-count
          run: |
            gh api graphql -f query='
              query($pr_url: URI!) {
                resource(url: $pr_url) {
                  ... on PullRequest {
                    baseRepository {
                      branchProtectionRules(first: 1) {
                        nodes {
                          requiredApprovingReviewCount
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }'  -f pr_url=$PR_URL > data.json
            echo 'REVIEW_REQUIRED_COUNT='$(jq '.data.resource.baseRepository.branchProtectionRules.nodes[] | .requiredApprovingReviewCount' data.json) >> $GITHUB_ENV

        - run: env
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a GitHub token permission issue